# Informatica workflow fails on failure of command task with UNCHECKED fail parent if task fails property

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a command task to call a batch file which returns 1 if File.Ok does not exists and 0 if File.Ok exists in a particular location. Following this command task I have 2 links:

link 1: $commandtask.status = succeeded

link 2: $commandtask.status = failed

After each of these links there are several session and other tasks.

PROBLEM: Whenever File.OK is not found, Link 2 is executed followed by tasks/sessions of this branch (as desired and expected) but after executing all remaining items the workflow gets failed.

note: I have not checked 'Fail Parent if task fails' property anywhere.

Comment: Share the specific error message from the workflow log files

Comment: I actually overlooked the workflow run properties. The workflow was getting failed as some session/task in a branch did not run due to conditional constraints and those session/task had 'fail parent if task failed property' checked.

Comment: I thought of suggesting that but the right first step is to look in the workflow logs rather than a shot in the dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have checked the "Fail parent if task does not run" in some task. If the task with this property checked does not run then it fails the workflow.